# Remove file of db backup from docker

Tags: docker

How can I remove a file backup from docker on macbook? the path of the file is :`/var/opt/mssql/data`. I tried with:

`sudo docker rm  841c43a742c4:/var/opt/mssql/data/file_name.bak`

but it doesn't work.

Error:

```
No such container: 841c43a742c4:/var/opt/mssql/data/file_name.bak
```

Comment: *but it doesn't work.* is not an error description. Any error message?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Remember that Stack Overflow is a site for asking programming questions specifically, so make sure to include any necessary application code to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
sudo docker exec <container_id> rm /var/opt/mssql/data/file_name.bak
```